# What means info file in createsamples opencv

Tags: opencv

I'm newbie in opencv, and I try create my first haar cascade classifier. I would like detect one simple card. I think, one good photo is enough.

What should I write to -info parametr when I have only one photo?

[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html#creating-training-set-as-a-collection-of-png-images) is writing that its file with annotations. What annotations? Maybe I can't read, I don't know, but I can't see any info about what should be in this file.

Answer (score 0):

In the info parameter you need to write the directory of the txt file or lst file which contains [ (directory of positive image) (number of objects) (top left coordinates) (width) (height)]
You can use ObjectMarker to create the info file.